# Custom priority value: is a pthread high sched prio positive or negative?

Tags: c, posix, scheduling, priority, pthreads

I’m trying to reimplement in a backward-compatible way the RobotC API from C (although some details would better fit or would be easier with C++), and trying [to reimplement their multithreading API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49458399/define-and-declare-and-use-global-variables-from-function-through-macros) in some portable way, so I try to use `sched_get_priority_max(2)` and `sched_get_priority_min(2)`. But on one hand `nice(1)` and `sched(7)` say priority is between -20 (highest priority) and 19 (lower priority), on another hand, the former man pages stated that:

> […] numerically higher priority values are  scheduled  before 
>   processes with numerically lower priority values.  Thus, the value
>   returned by sched_get_priority_max() will be greater than the value
>   returned by sched_get_priority_min()

which would mean the opposite: positive value being of higher priority and negative of lower priority (it also gives the example of real-time policies where priority is between 1 and 99).

What is going to be returned by `sched_get_priority_max` and `_min`? what should I use with `pthread_attr_setschedparam(3)`?

I have three values defining my custom priority range: the low priority (`kLowPriority`, set to 0), the high one (`kHighPriority`, set to 255) and the default one (`kDefaultPriority`, set to 7). Ideally I suppose the default being 0 for the scheduling policies having a default, `kDefaultPriority`/7 should become 0, `kHighPriority`/255 the highest priority (19? 99? whatever `sched_get_priority_max(3)` returns) or maybe the highest priority that can be assigned if unpriviledged? and then `kLowPriority` either `0 ± kDefaultPriority`, either the lowest priority …what would be the more reasonable?

Currently I think I do it this way:

```
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_t thread;
struct sched_param param;
const int policy = sched_getscheduler(0),
  sched_high_prio = sched_get_priority_max(policy), // 19,
  sched_low_prio = sched_get_priority_min(policy), // -20,
  sched_range_prio = sched_high_prio - sched_low_prio;
pthread_attr_init (&attr);
pthread_attr_getinheritsched(&attr, PTHREAD_INHERIT_SCHED);
pthread_attr_getschedparam (&attr, &param);
param.sched_priority = -(((nTaskPriority
                           - kLowPriority) * sched_range_prio
                          / kHighPriority) + sched_low_prio
                         - kDefaultTaskPriority);
```

PS: I’m not sure if the best place to ask this question about POSIX API is here or [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472763/custom-priority-value-is-a-pthread-high-sched-prio-positive-or-negative), so I’m doing both, please delete my post or ask me to delete if you think it’s at the wrong place.
EDIT: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49472763/custom-priority-value-is-a-pthread-high-sched-prio-positive-or-negative) deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you’re looking for a portable answer, but a good start to understand this is to look at the behaviour on Linux, as documented in the manpage for [`sched(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sched.7.html), in the “Scheduling policies” section:

> The scheduler is the kernel component that decides which runnable
>          thread will be executed by the CPU next.  Each thread has an
>          associated scheduling policy and a *static* scheduling priority,
>          *sched_priority*.  The scheduler makes its decisions based on knowledge
>          of the scheduling policy and static priority of all threads on the
>          system.
>
> For threads scheduled under one of the normal scheduling policies
>          (`SCHED_OTHER`, `SCHED_IDLE`, `SCHED_BATCH`), *sched_priority* is not used in
>          scheduling decisions (it must be specified as 0).
>
> Processes scheduled under one of the real-time policies (`SCHED_FIFO`,
>          `SCHED_RR`) have a *sched_priority* value in the range 1 (low) to 99
>          (high).  (As the numbers imply, real-time threads always have higher
>          priority than normal threads.)  Note well: POSIX.1 requires an
>          implementation to support only a minimum 32 distinct priority levels
>          for the real-time policies, and some systems supply just this
>          minimum.  Portable programs should use [sched_get_priority_min(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_get_priority_min.2.html) and
>          [sched_get_priority_max(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_get_priority_max.2.html) to find the range of priorities supported
>          for a particular policy.

See also [the POSIX documentation for `pthread_setschedparam`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_setschedparam.html), which only requires three policies (`SCHED_OTHER`, `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`), and states that behaviour under the first is implementation-defined.

So if you want to schedule threads using a priority, portably, you need to use the appropriate policy first (FIFO or round-robin). Then you determine the range of values, and set the priority as appropriate. Threads and processes are scheduled by decreasing priority: threads with a higher priority will run first.

On Linux, the default behaviour (implementation-defined as per POSIX) uses a dynamic priority which is calculated based on the `nice` value, and how often a given thread is *not* scheduled. On Linux, the `nice` value determines priority lowest-first, so -20 is the highest priority, 19 the lowest. POSIX describes `nice` as a per-process value, but on Linux it’s per-thread, so you can use to schedule threads there (but that’s not portable).